# Are mysql global variables values in bytes?

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

When I run the following in my mysql terminal

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'tmp_table_size';
+----------------+----------+
| Variable_name  | Value    |
+----------------+----------+
| tmp_table_size | 16777216 |
+----------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

This is probably very oblivious but is the value `16777216` in bytes?  I just want to be sure and can't seem to find a definitive answer on the web.

Is this the same for all values? Such as `query_cache_size` & `query_cache_limit`

I need to know this to set up a Amazon RDS Param group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is bytes. You also can not set anything other like

```
set session tmp_table_size = 8k;
```

This is only possible in configuration files. But you can do something like

```
set session tmp_table_size = 8 * 1024;
```

Comment: @tomborn, thanks. BTW way I'm needed to know this to set up a Amazon RDS Param group.